# Backbone design patterns similar to DAOs

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, dao

Overall I'm happy with using Backbone.js for my company's frontend application. However I've noticed a lot of foundational problems that I wonder if anyone else encountered.

The biggest issue is that the frontend team does not control the API that powers our application. The objects passed are fairly complex in structure.  Nested arrays, sub objects, etc.... This of itself is expected. The API serves a different purpose than the frontend. What each considers an "object" are completely different things.

In practice this leads to issues.  Namely, one API endpoint may be broken into multiple frontend models. This is a common problem when dealing with APIs. It's typically addressed through Data Access Objects or a Data Access Layers that translate API objects into internal objects.  Backbone by contrast expects models to be tightly coupled with the API endpoints. Sync operations on a model (i.e. save, fetch) immediately reach out to the API.

Adding to the issues, I seriously believe that toJSON in Backbone does too much. It's used to reproduce the model in a format that can be consumed internally; defines how the model should get posted to an API; and used for equality checks between models for many internal operations. Any of the three could get broken out into their own method.

Has anyone else dealt with this? What strategies did you use? Implement DAOs? Is there a fork of Backbone that accounts for these issues?

[edit]

A closer to real world case that I've encountered. When we query the API for results, there's about a hundred filters we can pass along with the request. The overall filter structure is pretty simple on that end an array of filter objects like so:

```
{
  filterName: '',
  // '~', '=', '<=', '>='
  operator: '',
  value: ''
}
```

For one particularly problematic filter, depending on the 'operator' we either allow the user to select a single option or we allow the user to construct a "sentence" from the available options. The former option renders as an HTML select, the latter we implemented with a lextree parser. Obviously the two necessitate wildly different code so we split this into two different classes, but to the API the filter is the same regardless of our implementation.

This is straightforward enough, but issues with Backbone come into how the classes are defined. We may want to make use of the built-in get/set functions. But this will dump properties into attributes, which affects the default toJSON which is also used to build the API representation of this filter, and whether this filter is equal to another filter of the same type.

With a Data Access pattern there'd be another layer that knew how to translate that filter to the API and vice versa. Any CRUD operation would get picked up by the specific DAO and processed by proxy.

Comment: Can you give an example of a typical problem?

Comment: @KimGysen updated the question with an example